# IL-Repack Dealing with Third Party Dependencies

Tags: ilrepack

I had a working IL-Repack post-build task in my project.  Recently, I updated a number of libraries and now I have an issue that I cannot figure out.

My project uses Newtonsoft.Json and I have updated it to v12.  My script is setup to take all dlls from the bin directory and merge them.  When it gets to a certain dll (Twilio in this case), it gives this exception.

Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Newtonsoft.Json, version=10.0.0.0, ...'.  So I'm assuming that dll is looking for the Newtonsoft.Json but is getting confused by version?

Running the program from Visual Studio does not have any issues.  Twilio requires Newtonsoft.Json 10+, so version 12 is ok.  How do I get IL-Repack to recognize the v12 Newtonsoft?  I can see that I've added Newtonsoft.Json for merge before Twilio is added.

This is for .net 4.7.2. IL-Repack 2.0.18 (current)

Comment: I don't know if it is the same issue, but take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74038729/4828907).